# Get max value of column after query results - sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

This isn't a standard `MAX(column_name)` answer I don't think.

Basically, I want the query to return a table with an added column `MaxTotalRev`. That column should only be populated IF it is the row with the max value for TotalRev. All other rows should have this column be empty.

This should not affect the order by which the results are returned. Instead it should just be an additional column on the returned table.

i.e

```
total_rev | max_total_rev
-------------------------
    1     |     null
    3     |      3
    2     |     null
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? mysql <> sql server. Your answers will be different depending.

Comment: Ok. So what have attempted so far? This site is for questions, it is not a place to dump your to-do list and expect someone else to do your job for you.

Comment: You can use a sub-select among many other things for this.

Comment: `SELECT MAX(TotalRev)` doesn't work because it populates every row and the value isn't even the max im looking for. `GROUP BY` doesn't work because it 1) alters how the data is grouped and that's not what I want and 2) doesn't help me quickly find the row with the max value out of all the other rows. `ORDER BY` wont work because again, i don't want the data to be ordered by this value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one option using a `window function` -- `max / over` -- with a `case` statement:

```
select total_rev,
  case when total_rev = max(total_rev) over () then total_rev end as max_total_rev 
from yourtable
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4fb6a/1)